# Catch double click in QTableView's unused area

Tags: c++, mouseevent, double-click, qtableview, qt4.8

My application starts with an empty table, and I want to imlement different methods to add items. One should be by double-clicking the table's unused area (or "background") that is not occupied by any cells. When a cell is double-clicked, I want the default behavior.

I've found way to do this by re-implementing `QAbstractScrollArea::mouseDoubleClickEvent()` method in my `TestTable` class:

```
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QTableView>

class TestTable : public QTableView
{
  Q_OBJECT
  signals:
    void backgroundDoubleClickEvent(void);
  protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent (QMouseEvent* e)
    {
      if (indexAt(e->pos()).isValid())
      {
          QTableView::mouseDoubleClickEvent(e);
      }
      else
      {
        e->accept();
        emit backgroundDoubleClickEvent();
      }

    }
};
```

- This works, but is there a more elegant way of doing this without subclassing `QTableView`?
- I'm not aware of any limitations of my current implementation. Are there obvious caveats?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to subclass `QTableView`, try [installEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter)

Comment: I'll try that, thanks! It looks a bit more complicated and I'll have to find out how to catch a double click, but that's not totally out of reach.